# unable to use npm after update

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have installed node on ubuntu with the following command -

```
$sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Now with this, I got npm version 2.14 and node v4.2. Now since the latest version of npm is 3.x so I tried to update the npm via command

```
$sudo npm install -g npm
    /usr/bin/npm -> /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@3.3.12 /usr/lib/node_modules/npm
```

So it runs just fine but after the update when I type npm -v it says -

```
bash: /usr/bin/npm: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I am unable to get the error, I tried a couple of question's answer from StackOverflow and GitHub but still no success.

Thanks

Comment: Your best solution is probably going to be to use something like [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) so you can get out of sudo hell without taking ownership of `/usr/lib/`.

Comment: Ok but as far as i can understand it just rolls back or updates my node to any version, does it work for npm as well??

Comment: It does more than that. Yes it lets you install any version on the fly, but even if you only use one version it configures the environment so that both node & npm operate out of `~/.nvm` or any other directory you specify. Brings everything out of `/usr/lib` and eliminates tons of headaches.